# Difference between : &data[0] vs. data

Tags: c, pass-by-reference

When I want to pass an array by reference to a function I don't know what to choose.

```c
void myFunction(int* data);
```

Is there a difference or a best coding way between those two cases:

```c
myFunction(&data[0]);
```

**Or**

```c
myFunction(data);
```

Comment: No difference from the syntax point of view. The `&data[0]` is a bit longer but much more informative to the observer. It says that `data` is not just some variable but an array and you are passing the address of the beginning of it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no difference. Arrays ("proper" arrays) automatically *decay* to pointers to their first element.

For example, lets say you have

```
int my_array[10];
```

then using plain `my_array` will automatically decay to a pointer to its first element, which is `&my_array[0]`.

It is this array-to-pointer decay that allows you to use both pointer arithmetic and array indexing for both arrays and pointers. For the array above `my_array[i]` is exactly equal to `*(my_array + i)`. This equivalence also exists for pointers:

```
int *my_pointer = my_array;  // Make my_pointer point to the first element of my_array
```

Then `my_pointer[i]` is *also* exactly equal to `*(my_pointer + i)`.

---

For curiosity (and something you should never do in real programs), thanks to the [commutative property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutative_property) of addition an expression such as `*(my_array + i)` will also be equal to `*(i + my_array)` which is then equal to `i[my_array]`.

Answer (score 3):

Apart from the obvious (`data` being shorter than `&data[0]`; therefore easier to write and to read), there's no difference.

Think about what `&data[0]` means:

- It's a pointer to `data[0]`.
- And `data[0]` just means `*(data+0)`, i.e. `*data`.
- A pointer to `*data` is simply `data`.

Answer (score 2):

An array, when passed as a parameter to a function, automatically *decays* to a pointer to its first element.  So passing either `data` or `&data[0]` to the function are exactly equivalent.

From a readability standpoint I would opt for the former.  It makes it clear to the reader that the function is potentially operating on the entire array and not just on one element.

Comment: Conversely, if you know the function operates only on the single element, rather than treating as an array, it may communicate intent to write `&data[0]`, though that is unusual to see.

Answer (score 1):

No difference. When coerced into a pointer, an array (`data`) decays into a pointer to its first element (`&data[0]`).

Remember that `data[0]` simply means `*(data+0)`, so `&data[0]` is equivalent to `&*(data+0)`, which simplifies to `data` (because `&*` cancels out).

Demo:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
   int data[2];
   printf("%p\n", (void*)data);
   printf("%p\n", (void*)&*(data+0));
   printf("%p\n", (void*)&data[0]);
   return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
$ gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic a.c -o a && a
0x3c2180f4fa0
0x3c2180f4fa0
0x3c2180f4fa0
```

Answer (score 1):

data is a pointer to the beginning of the array.
&data[0] is an address of the first element of an array.

When reading a code, the first option is, for the most people, more readable and i suppose is a way most programmers will and should choose

Comment: “data is a pointer to the beginning of the array” — No. It’s the array itself. It *decays to* a pointer, but that isn’t the same thing, as you can easily check by inspecting the value of `sizeof data`. As for “easier to read” — you can make this argument but at least one answerer gives a compelling opposing argument, so it’s clearly not universal.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't any difference as both point to the same starting location of the array i.e. a[0].

Answer (score 1):

I always advice to use a general approach.

Just consider the function

```
void myFunction( char* data);
```

where the parameter has the type `char *` instead of `int *`.

And now let's assume that you want to pass to the function a string literal.

It can be done either like

```
myFunction( "Hello" );
```

or like

```
myFunction( &"Hello"[0] );
```

It is evident that the first approach is more clear and readable.

So I prefer to use the first approach.:)

In fact such an expression

```
&data[i];
```

is syntactically redundant.. In fact it looks like

```
&( *( data + i ) )
```

that is equivalent to just

```
data + i
```

When `i` is equal to 0 then you have

```
data + 0
```

that in expressions  is equivalent (I do not take into account for example the sizeof operaor) to

```
data
```

So use `data` instead of `&data[0]`.

Answer (score 1):

I would just use `my_function(data)` because why make it more confusing than it has to be?

If for some reason you needed to find the memory address of a single element somewhere in the middle of data, then `my_function(&data[17])` might possibly be warranted, but there are probably better ways to handle that case too.

In general if you have to manually and specifically pick out single pieces of data like that by hand, you are probably not doing it in a very good way.

There are rare cases where it can makes sense ( like if you are parsing data from some other source and you ALWAYS 100% of the time only care about the 17th byte )... but that's not usually the case.

Consider the following:
As your code evolves and you make changes, you will probably also slightly change data structures. Data[17] might no longer be the magical byte that you need anymore. Now it might be data[18]. If you manually hard coded data[17] in 100 or 1000 different places in your code, you will now have to go manually change them all and hope that it doesn't cause any new bugs. Also... portability issues.

Instead design functions that can find and return whatever data you need from your data structures without needing any hard coded addresses. They will still work ( if designed properly ) as your code evolves and will be 1000 times more portable.